# Make pc let you choose UEFI or legacy, on startup

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, bios, uefi

I have doul boot windows 10 and ubuntu on my dell laptop, but the ubuntu is on the Legacy and the windows is on UEFI. So i want to choose UEFI or legacy every time i start the computer.

Comment: This won’t be possible.  You have to power cycle a machine in order to save the settings.  Ubuntu and Windows both support UEFI

Comment: If you have difficulty, run Ubuntu as a Virtual Machine.  I do this and it works very well

Comment: @John Why the OP should run an OS in virtual environment if not needed? Note I could have done the same question for the opposite too (run a virtual instance of windows).

Comment: Dual Boot seems limiting to me because of the underlying changes that go on. That is why I suggest it